# How to create persistence , domain and view models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been reading a lot about the importance of keeping layers separately and the concepts are mind blowing :) . However,I looked into many places to find a practical example on how to separate these three types of models and had no luck. How do I connect them together in a practical situation?  Here are few questions I have

1. My understanding is that persistence models contain the POCOs that we use to create entities , domain models contain the business logic and view models are used to expose relevant data. Am I correct?
2. If I am correct , how do I actually connect these different layers in a single solution. I mean at the end of the day , they are classes and how do I connect domain class(model) with a relevant persistence (model) and the view model?

Can someone please point me to a great tutorial that teaches how to build n-tire asp.net applications?

If not, and if possible can someone tell me how to build and connect three types of models for the following scenario.

A Customer has a Name , DOB , Address and  a collection of Orders

An Order has a Customer, Date , Price and a Description

How do I create separate persistence, domain and view models(eg: A view model to display all information about customer except DOB  and all orders related to the customer )

More importantly how do I connect them?

Thanks heaps!
Cheers!

Comment: Are you looking for architectural layers?

Comment: Yes please. How do I connect them together? I mean how to do create a separate domain model to an existing persistence model?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552487/Understanding-Multilayered-Architecture-in-NET

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response Manoz. I have been through that article before. However, I don't think it demonstrates what I want. I'm trying to use code first approach and the closest tutorial I found was  http://imar.spaanjaars.com/573/aspnet-n-layered-applications-introduction-part-1 . Even that doesn't separate Domain models from Persistence models.

Comment: Hi, I finally managed to find a scratch development of Layers. Hope it helps you- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/create-and-implement-3-tier-architecture-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Ok. So for an example, If I want to create a customer persistence model and Domain model , Should I pass Customer Persistence model objects to Domain model methods?

Answer (score 1):

you create viewmodels to match the view, not every property from the model (Entity) you might want to show in the Create/Edit view, or you want to show it but combined or in a different way, that's why you need viewmodels, usually you would have a property in the viewmodel for each editor/input in the view

for example in the Entity you can have one DateTime property but in the ViewModel 2 properties one for Date and one for Time,
or in the Entity you will have property of type Country but in the ViewModel of type int (the value of the id)

and when you have this separation you need to map Entities to ViewModels and the other way around

for demo app you can look here: http://prodinner.codeplex.com/